# XPath in T-SQL update schema

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, xquery, xml-dml

In my table I have a column with `XML` data.

For example lets say that schema is as below:

```
<person>
  <id></id>
  <name></name>
</person>
```

Problem is that some of these nodes has got additional node `<lastname>`

Now I would like to update all elements in this column so that each one has got node `lastname` with default value, for example `smith`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE 
    dbo.YourTable
SET 
    XmlColumn.modify('insert <lastname>Smith</lastname> as last into (/person)[1]')
WHERE 
    XmlColumn.exist('/person/lastname') = 0
```

This updates all rows where the `<lastname>` node does **not** exist inside `<person>`, and insert `<lastname>Smith</lastname>` into those XML values.

**Update:** if you want to pick certain names, use this query:

```
UPDATE 
    dbo.YourTable
SET 
    XmlColumn.modify('insert <lastname>Smith</lastname> as last into (/person)[1]')
WHERE 
    XmlColumn.exist('/person[name="John"]') = 1
```

**Update #2:** to prove my query is right - try this little test here:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (ID INT, XmlCol XML)

INSERT INTO @test 
   VALUES(1, '<person><id>1</id><name>John</name></person>'),
         (2, '<person name="John"><id>2</id><name>Fred</name></person>'),
         (3, '<person><id>3</id><name>Wally</name></person>')

SELECT *
FROM @test
WHERE XmlCol.exist('/person[name="John"]') = 1
```

If you run this (on SQL Server 2008 or newer), you will get:

```
1    <person><id>1</id><name>John</name></person>
```

as the output; the selection criteria is testing on the **XML element** `<name>` having a value of `John`

Comment: How can I filter only users with name john ? Thanks for guick answeer

Comment: @gruber: no you are wrong on this one; the query I specified is checking for the value of "John" inside an **XML element** called `name` - **NOT** an XML attribute! This **will** select entries where you have `<person><name>John</name></person>` - try it!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28SQL.90%29.aspx

There you can find this:

```
UPDATE docs SET xCol.modify('
  insert 
   <section num="2">   
        <title>Background</title>
   </section>
  after (/doc//section[@num=1])[1]')
```

HTH

Comment: How is this taking into account that *some* of the <person> nodes already have a <lastname> subnode?? This will insert a new node into **all** rows - that's **not** what the OP is looking for

Comment: I was just giving him an example which I found in that link (a big article)....Your answer makes sense and I have already given a +1 for that :-)